# mysql load testing tools

Tags: mysql, size, load-testing

I want to calculate the each row size of a table. are there any tools available for this. Also Does anyone aware of any load testing tools.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Manasi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Calculate average row size with:

  [`SHOW TABLE STATUS [FROM databasename] [LIKE 'pattern']`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html)
- [Super Smack](http://vegan.net/tony/supersmack/) is a benchmarking, stress testing, and load generation tool for MySQL (and PostgreSQL).