# How do you repeat a raw SQL query # times to MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, benchmarking

I want to test the load a MySQL server can handle using a couple versions of a query and for that I'm looking for something like apachebench (but for mysql).

I'm hoping to run 500 or more concurrent requests every second for a couple minutes and see if MySQL is up to the challenge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql load testing tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593498/mysql-load-testing-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [Super Smack](http://vegan.net/tony/supersmack/) solve your problem?